# Knapsack DP returning incorrect answer

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

My memoized knapsack O/1 problem results in a smaller answer than expected for some test cases.

```
Test case

maxWeight = 1000

weights = [3,68,24,80,76,9,24,2,46,75,56,41,95,46,23,34,64,76,6,48,25,73,87]

values =[38,16,29,47,22,25,17,49,15,15,75,11,56,99,51,92,59,37,13,98,61,50,32]


  def dynamicProgramming(self,weights,values,maxWeight,currValue,index,dp):
        if index < 0:
            return currValue
            
        item_weight = weights[index]
        
        if (index,maxWeight) in dp:
            return dp[(index,maxWeight)]
        
        if item_weight > maxWeight:
            skip_item = self.dynamicProgramming(weights,values,maxWeight,currValue,index - 1,dp)
            dp[(index,maxWeight)] = skip_item
            return skip_item
        else:
            new_val = currValue + values[index]
            remaining_weight = maxWeight-item_weight
            dp[(index,maxWeight)] = max(self.dynamicProgramming(weights,values,remaining_weight,new_val,index - 1,dp),self.dynamicProgramming(weights,values,maxWeight,currValue,index - 1,dp))
            
            return dp[(index,maxWeight)]
```

I get the correct answer when instead of passing the updated value as an argument to the function, I add the value to the returned call.

```
dp[(index,maxWeight)] = max(values[index] + self.dynamicProgramming(weights,values,remaining_weight,new_val,index - 1,dp),self.dynamicProgramming(weights,values,maxWeight,currValue,index - 1,dp))
```

and update the base case to return 0. Why does passing the updated value as an argument to the function result in an incorrect answer?